# how to check a row for duplicate ones?

Tags: excel, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, no-duplicates

I have a openoffice calculator where I have some transactions... there are 3 columns that I need to compare as one... they can be repeated individually or in peer but never those 3 at the same time by other row... so I need some idea so I can check that there are no rows duplicated.... any idea :D ?????

Example:

columne1..columne2..Columne3....checkcolumne (just and idea).................................
....111...........222...........333............ok.............................................................................................................111...........222...........444............ok............................................................................................................
  111 .........     222   .........   333   ......    Duplicate

there are more than 3 columnes of info, but there are 3 that i need to check

Answer (score 1):

To avoid failing to distinguish between `112` with `22` and `11` with `222` I'd suggest concatenating with a delimiter, say:

```
=A1&"#"&B1&"#"&C1
```

and if to identify how many instances a formula such as `=COUNTIF(D$1:D$6,D1)` with both formulae copied down to suit and the `6` adjusted to suit. If to identify the first of pairs of entries this could be adjusted to `=COUNTIF(D$1:D$6,D1)-1`, with `0` ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would to it in excel. Use  =CONCATENATE(column1,2,3) and run a pivot table on it to count how many there are. Assuming you have access to excel.

Comment: yeah, i did that, but the problem is that there are to many data, that crashes when i used that formula D:

Comment: IF it crashes after the first step I usually copy the concatenate column and past as data over it. Then do the nest step